# Floating footer with switching languages in I18n RoR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

Here's something that I've been struggling with for a long time which doesn't seem to go away. I have a gallery page with images. For the loading of the page, and images especially, I've inserted a preloader icon, which spins for 2000 milliseconds until it disappears and the page reappears. The footer is set thru `#myFooter` to `display: none;` by default and after the loading of 2 seconds thru JS the style is changed to `display: flex;` again.

However, I have 2 different footers, one made for the gallery page and one for the other pages. The one for the gallery page has `#myFooter` id and other one doesn't. That's because without this id, you would see the footer floating right underneath the header (navbar).

I have also made the entire website in 2 languages thru the use of I18n inside RoR. Due to this, the disappearing `display: none;` css only happens in one of the languages (English) while with the other language (Spanish) it's not showing. So when I'm switching to English the page somehow loads the footer that was only meant for the other pages, but not the gallery page. While switching to Spanish it does load the right footer.

Here's the html:

Footer without id `#myFooter`:

```
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

Footer with id `#myFooter`:

```
<div id="myFooter" class="footer">
</div>
```

`application.html.erb`:

```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Ibiza Wedding Ceremonies</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%#= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all' %> <!-- Uncomment if you import CSS in app/javascript/packs/application.js -->
  </head>
  <body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">
    <% if current_page?(root_path) %>
      <%= render 'shared/banner' %>
      <%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
      <%= render 'shared/topbtn' %>
    <% elsif current_page?(pages_about_path) %>
      <%= render 'shared/navbar-2' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'shared/navbar-2' %>
      <%= render 'shared/topbtn' %>
    <% end %>

    <%= render 'shared/flashes' %>
    <%= yield %>
    <% if current_page?(gallery_index_path) %>
      <%= render 'shared/footer-2' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
    <% end %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the css:

`_footer.scss`:

```
#myFooter {
  display: none;
}

.footer {
  background: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.footer-links a {
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.15;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.footer-links a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.footer .fa-heart {
  color: #D23333;
}
```

`_loader.scss`:

```
/* Center the loader */

#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom {
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here's the JavaScript:

`pre-loader.js`:

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 2000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("myFooter").style.display = "flex";
}
```

`routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users

  get '/change_locale/:locale', to: 'settings#change_locale', as: :change_locale
  get '/:locale' => 'pages#home'

  root to: 'pages#home'

  scope '(:locale)', locale: /en|es/ do
    root to: 'pages#home'
    get 'pages/contact'
    get 'pages/weddings'
    get 'pages/about'
    get 'pages/press'
    get 'pages/other_ceremonies'
    get 'pages/press/ibiza-si-quiero', to: 'pages#si_quiero', as: :si_quiero
    get 'pages/press/celebrating-love', to: 'pages#celebrating_love', as: :celebrating_love
    # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
    resources :testimonials
    resources :photos, only: [:index], as: :gallery
  end
end
```

So my question is: How do I get the floating footer to disappear on both the English and Spanish page?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I've added my question.